# Custom Annotation Processor working in Maven but not in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, annotation-processing

I have a custom Annotation Processor which is being used in a sample project. I have added the following in the pom.xml file of the sample project

```
  <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessor>com.******.CustomAnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-Amyarg=${project.artifactId}</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I then declare the argument in the application.properties file as follows:

```
@myarg@.someVal=foobar
```

And access it as follows “

```
public class TestClass {
@Value("${@myarg@.someVal}")
private String testVal;

public void testMethod(){
    System.out.println(testVal);
}
}
```

It is working fine in Intelli J as testVal prints out to be foobar. However, in eclipse I get the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating     bean with name ‘testClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder ‘@myarg@.someVal’ in string value "${@myarg@.someVal}"
```

I understand that Eclipse uses its own compiler, while Maven probably uses javac. How do I get this custom annotation working for eclipse as well?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404891/how-to-configure-java-annotation-processors-in-eclipse

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404891/how-to-configure-java-annotation-processors-in-eclipse) Or convert your project into maven project in Eclipse.

Comment: What is mentioned in this post isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps to enable annotation processing.

1. Right click on the project and select `Properties`.
2. In `Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing`. Check `Enable annotation processing`.

[image]

3. Open `Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing -> Factory Path`. Check `Enable project specific settings`. Add your JAR file to the list.

[image]
4. Clean and build the project.

Comment: Excuse me If I am asking something obvious but what exactly do you mean by "your JAR". Custom Annotation Processor's jar ?

Comment: You must have a jar with custom annotation and annotation processor?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem.

99% of the solution was as **gyan** described.

The last 1% was for eclipse I needed "jar" files needed specify all needed jar files in the "Factory Path".

For my project this meant

1. the annotation-definition project jar,
2. the annotation-processing project jar, and
3. javapoet.jar.