# Symbol not found and Annotation Processing

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was going through https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder

In it they are creating

```
public class PersonBuilder {
 
    private Person object = new Person();
 
    public Person build() {
        return object;
    }
 
    public PersonBuilder setName(java.lang.String value) {
        object.setName(value);
        return this;
    }
 
    public PersonBuilder setAge(int value) {
        object.setAge(value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

to use

```
Person person = new PersonBuilder()
  .setAge(25)
  .setName("John")
  .build();
```

But since the PersonBuilder is generated at compile time wouldn't the ide throw a symbol not found error or am i missing something?

Comment: I dont understand your question at all :).  Please clarify what it is that you are confused about exactly?  I also suggest you read about the Builder Pattern :)

Comment: @SusanMustafa PersonBuilder returns a new Person object. Click on the link i shared in question its a tutorial about Annotation Processing to create source-code at compile time so PersonBuilder will be created at compile time. So how do we refer to it while writing normal code

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple steps you would need to work with Annotation Processing:

- You would need to enable it in the compiler or add it in your mvn compile plugin.
- You need to enable annotation processing in your IDE [How to configure Java Annotation Processor(s) in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404891/how-to-configure-java-annotation-processors-in-eclipse)

Lombomk is another example of annotations.  You would write @Data, @Getters, but you can use getAttribute(), and setAttribute() without actually writting them in the code, though you would have to have it in your pom.xml and enabled in your IDE.