# Spring boot lombok @AllArgsConstructor issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lombok

This is my entity package and I have an error indicating the fields are not used and I can’t call getter and setters.

It's like Lombok is not working. What exactly is the solution?

```
package com.app.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "userregister")
public class User {

    private String name;
    
    @Id
    private String username;

    private String email;

    private String phone;

    private String password;
    
    private String cpassword;

    private String gender;

}
```

[image: this is my controller class in the picture]

Comment: Have you setup Eclipse properly to work with Lombok? https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Comment: Yes i did but it still doesn't show

Comment: I assume this is an existing project, right? Does it work properly for your colleagues? Does it compile properly when you build with Maven, i.e., not from inside Eclipse?

Comment: Perhaps check on how to enable annotation processors in Eclipse or check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404891/how-to-configure-java-annotation-processors-in-eclipse/44674739)

Answer (score 0):

```
The code seems fine.May be your ide is not recognizing lombok dependency.

Please try to add the following dependency into your pom.xml file
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

and Download lombok.jar from the given link
https://projectlombok.org/download

Now if it is zipped unzip it first and then copy it to the directory 
where you have your SpringToolSuits(STS installed).

Let say your STS version is 4.11.0.RELEASE then copy lombok.jar to STS 
directory/sts-4.11.0.RELEASE   i.e. inside STS/sts-4.11.0.RELEASE/

Now try to rebuild and update your project.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70934552/sonar-doesnt-pick-lombok-annotations-remove-unused-private-field

Thanks
```