# Sonar Doesn't pick lombok Annotations ( Remove unused private field)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube, lombok

I am using sonar version 8.9.6.
I know this issue has been asked around a lot of times and I have tried a lot of those and none of the solutions have worked for me.

The following are some of the things that I have tried:

1)

```xml
<sonar.exclusions>
// my domain package here
</sonar.exclusions>
```

2. added the following plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includeArtifactIds>lombok</includeArtifactIds>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and then added the following property

```xml
<sonar.java.libraries>target/dependency/*.jar</sonar.java.libraries>
```

3. Added `lombok.config` and added the following properties

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

None of these have worked for me and especially sonar exclusions doesn't work at all.
Any help would be appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the following dependency into your `pom.xml` file

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and Download `lombok.jar` from the given link
https://projectlombok.org/download

Now if it is zipped unzip it first and then copy it to the directory
where you have your SpringToolSuits(STS installed).

Let say your STS version is `4.11.0.RELEASE` then copy `lombok.jar` to STS
`directory/sts-4.11.0.RELEASE`   i.e. inside `STS/sts-4.11.0.RELEASE/`

Now try to rebuild and update your project.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, i have a tiny trick. I used Schema annotation of swagger and the problem pass with me.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class AccessLog {
    @Schema(description = "User ID")
    private String userId;

    @Schema(description = "Action Code")
    private String actionCode;

    @Schema(description = "User Agent")
    private String userAgent;
}
```